# jQuery: Loading external HTML content; Access to elements inserted fails

Tags: jquery, html, dom, load

I would like to load a *table* element from another HTML (additional_content.html) into the current HTML via jQuery. I managed to load the content but I am not able to access the elements inserted as if they were not inserted. However, when inserting an *alert* statement just after the *load* statement, I am able to access the elements of the *table* inserted via *load*. It appears to me that the DOM tree is not updated immediately.

The code fragment within the parent document looks like this:

```
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
  $("#content").load("additonal_content.html #content table").hide();
  $("#content").find("img").each(function() {
    alert("test");
  });
</script>
```

And the table within *additional_content.html" is (excerpt):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="image1.gif"></td>
    <td>some text...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="image2.gif"></td>
    <td>some text...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: HTML is not updated after manipulating <img src> paths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194691/jquery-html-is-not-updated-after-manipulating-img-src-paths)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the content hasn't loaded yet when it hits the 'find' statement.

Try using a callback, a la:

```
<script>
$("#content").load("additonal_content.html #content table",function(){
 $("#content").find("img").each(function() {
    alert("test");
 });
});
 </script>
```

Comment: The next problem. The update of the *src* attribute is not reflected in the rendered HTML. If I look via Firebug in the HTML code, the new *src* paths are up to date.

Comment: $("#content").load("additonal_content.html #content table", function() {
    $("#content").find("img").each(function() {
      $(this).attr("src", "new_folder/" + $(this).attr("src"));
    });
  });

Comment: Hmm, might be best if you post this as a new question. Do you have a live site we can look at?

Comment: Here we go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194691/jquery-html-is-not-updated-after-manipulating-img-src-paths   Unfortunately, I have no working live example, yet.