# SRC change jQuery ? - ( Handheld devices )

Tags: jquery, mobile, src

I have faced a strange problem, when manipulating image, and iframe SRC-s in jQuery.

On handheld devices ( tested on **Android/Chrome** and **iPad/Safari** ) the src change simply **doesn't reload the source** with the actual content. This works like charm on any computer.

**UPDATE:**

My approach simplified as much as possible:

```
function decompress(){
    $("img.foo").attr("src",newsrc)); // where newsrc is http://foo.bar/img/foo.png
}
```

And I am calling this function this way `$(window).on("load",function(){decompress();});`

**UPDATE:**

I have seen this discussion: [jQuery: HTML is not updated after manipulating <img src> paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194691/jquery-html-is-not-updated-after-manipulating-img-src-paths?rq=1) , so I would like to make it clear, I am not using it on local, but on webserver, and the SRC-s are full URL-s through `http://` protocol.

**UPDATE:**

I have tried to not use the image cache with the url request trick ( [Refresh image with a new one at the same url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077041/refresh-image-with-a-new-one-at-the-same-url) ) with no avail. My code looked like:

```
o.attr("src",o.attr("src").replace("-300x168","?") + Math.random() );
```

with absolutely no changes in the functionality. Firefox, Chrome, Chromium, but even Safari, or IE8 does great job on computer. However, I cannot make iPad/Safari, or Android/Chrome work properly. I don't know, what the problem can possibly be, it might show up on more handheld devices as well.

**UPDATE:**

My full (related) actual function looks like this:

```
var ce=$("img[src*='-300x168']");
for(var i=0;i<ce.length;i++){
    var o=$(ce[i]);
    o.attr("src",o.attr("src").replace("-300x168","") + "?" + Math.random() );
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? How could I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried using [`.prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/)?

Comment: Does exactly the same with .prop()